# Why am I getting inconsistent conversions between a binary value and a character?

Tags: c++, arduino

Working with arduino. I have the following code in a function that is run twice during a process:

```
int hours = 7;
char hour = hours+'0';
debug(&hour);
char hour2 = hours+'0';
debug(&hour2);
```

The `debug` function is:

```
void debug(char message[]) {
  if (debugEnabled == true) {
    Serial.println(message);
  }
}
```

The global `debugEnabled` flag is initialized to `true`.

I'm getting the following output from every time the full process runs (hence executing the first code block twice):

```
7 
7 
72 
7
```

I can't see any reason I'm getting 72 in there on the second time the first variable is written, especially as the `hour2` variable is printed correctly every time.

Any suggestions as to what might be going wrong or how to further debug this would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you treat a single character as a string. A string in C needs to be terminated by an extra `'\0'` character. All string handling functions continue until they find this terminator character, and will go beyond any array limits you may have and producing unexpected and undefined results.

Comment: Very good point. I knew that too, I terminate the other strings I'm building with a null. That leads on to the next question... I'll give you the points for this one and open another after I've fixed my mishap in that bit of debugging code.